# Load-balancing - how does it affect ping?

Tags: networking, routing, ping

I notice how when I use the *ping* command to measure *ICMP* request to a nearby server, I see slightly different results each time I artificially reboot my connection without changing WAN IP.

For instance, if we assume that my ISP and the server are connected to each other with 3 different 10GB links of which have different length in directions, will my results differ sometimes due to the fact that both networks are using load-balancing to establish one connection randomly to one link, and use the other links as backups?

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that your ICMP traffic may be taking different paths due to load balancing mechanisms.  [QoS (Quality of Service)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) treatments can also affect the consistency of your ICMP replies.  Sometimes ICMP traffic is treated lower than other traffic and delayed at times network of congestion.